# Python Selenium - Find all Table Values with xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

So I have a table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's my code to find the a random element inside

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Smith']")
```

I think I can get the parent which is the `<tr>` that `<td> Smith` is in by doing this

`parent = table.parent`

But my goal is to find the `<table>` and print out all the values in them such as...

`Firstname, Lastname, Age, Jill, Smith......`

I'm not really sure how to go about doing this since the table has no Class and Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below snippet.

```
nodes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr/*")
for node in nodes:
    print(node.text)
```